# Remove the button border including the 'tab event' in wpf?

Tags: wpf, button

I manage to remove the button border completely by using this style

```
    <Style x:Key="TransparentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

However, how to remove the dotted black border that appears with the TAB key?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that would be the [FocusVisualStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle.aspx) showing that dotted line, try to set it to x:Null

Comment: It works like charm. Here's the source to share out. `<Button x:Name="Button1" Width="475" Height="89" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" FocusVisualStyle ="{x:Null}" >`

Comment: @user2711132 yups, or if you're using the TransparentStyle you shared back there you can just put it in the style's setter